# Bitcoin Armory startup issues

Tags: synchronization, armory

I have an issue with Bitcoin Armory. I have run it on Win 7, Armory version is 0.93.3-beta. I have run it at least once a week an so far it worked properly. Now it wont sync with the network (jams at 0 %, with an error message popping up after some time). Usually this was done in half an hour or sooner. I did not change anything.

Now the solution, that I have come across was to migrate it to another computer. I have an Ubuntu home computer on which the same problem appears. I have installed Armory, but it wont start with the sync. It starts the "Initializing Torrent Engine" but stays at 0 %. So perhaps this is not an computer issue after all. Any ideas on how to get hold of my bitcoins? The Armory support did not respond. At least not yet.